# Speed up polymerisation of formaldehyde

Tags: polymers

Is there a way to speed up the formation of para-formaldehyde in a formalin solution?

Comment: In pure enough formaldehyde, that is, with low methanol content, para-formaldehyde will start forming as a precipitate, but very slowly. I have tried finding some answers by simply googling, but all I get is how to make formaldehyde out of para-formaldehyde...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this patent](https://www.google.co.in/patents/US2551365), alkaline catalyst of composition sodium and potassium hydroxides, carbonates, formates, and acetates can be used to speed up formation of paraformaldehyde from formalin solution (aq. formaldehyde).

> This invention relates to a new and improved process for the
>   production of formaldehyde polymers. More particularly it relates to a
>   process whereby high strength aqueous formaldehyde solutions can be
>   concentrated to paraformaldehyde **at a greatly accelerated rate.**

Moreover, the patent describes the process of this reaction in details. Have a good read.